# Replicate a Calculation Sheet for each customer

Tags: worksheet-function, printing, database, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I created a LibreOffice sheet, with the detailed list of expenses. And a second list with the names and debts of each neighbour.

However, I'd like to generate a personalise replica of the first worksheet, including at the end the amount to pay (according to the second sheet).

*Question(s)*

- Is it possible to generate a bunch of sheets according to the data in the second worksheet? How?
- How could I after that print all the generated sheets automatically? (I have no interest in going over 100 sheets to click print every single time)

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the complexity of the sheets to generate. If those sheets aren't too complex, you could use your "master sheet" as a data source for a LO Writer (!) template file. Using the mail merge wizard, you could create individual "sheets" in Writer (!) for every neighbour and send them to the printer directly. Alternatively, you could make the Mail Merge Wizard create one big writer document, combining all the result "sheets".